# What does @ContextConfiguration refer to?

Tags: java, spring

I've just parachuted into a spring project and they don't believe in unit testing.

I am trying to set up my own unit testing environment.

May I know what does the annotation `@ContextConfiguration` refer to?

What about for @Repository, I can't seem to initialize it.

What does the file look like and where is it usually resided?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

Comment: @NimChimpsky that was quite inundating to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ContextConfiguration` is used to determine how to load and configure an `ApplicationContext` in integratrion tests, like in this JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test5.xml")
public class Test5 {
    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory f1;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It defines class-level metadata that is used to determine how to load and configure an
application context for integration tests.

Typically my spring unit test class look like this

```
@ContextConfiguration("/personservicetest-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PersonServiceTest {
  ...
}
```

And a spring application context will be built based on personservicetest-context.xml file (relative to classpath root)